# API request using Ntlm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am currently creating a VS-Code extension using Typescript.
Currently I am struggling to make an API request with the authentication Ntlm.
I have already tested the API in Postman, so the problem is with the code.

My current code:
import { NtlmClient } from 'node-ntlm-client';

```
const client = new NtlmClient();

client.request({
    url: 'https://your-business-central-api-url.com/api/your-endpoint',
    method: 'get',
    username: 'your-username',
    password: 'your-password',
    workstation: '',
    domain: 'your-domain'
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});`
```

The problem here is that I can't even get to the `client.request()`, as soon as it is at `const client = new NtlmClient()` it makes an exit without an error.

Any ideas or other ways I can solve this?

Comment: Should you not await it because it's a promise ? `await client.request()....`

Comment: You're right, but that sadly didn't solve it